# Не подключается к БД в Bitrix VM

Tags: mysql, битрикс

Разворачиваю сайт из бэкапа на Bitrix VM. Сайт на PHP 5, в виртуалке стоит PHP 7. Вроде проблем с переносом не должно возникнуть,
При попытке зайти на сайт пишет:

```
[Bitrix\Main\DB\ConnectionException] 
Mysql connect error [localhost, 127.0.0.1] (400)
/home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/db/mysqlconnection.php:49
#0: Bitrix\Main\DB\MysqlConnection->connectInternal()
   /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/db/mysqlconnection.php:105
#1: Bitrix\Main\DB\MysqlConnection->queryInternal(string, array, NULL)
   /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/db/connection.php:329
#2: Bitrix\Main\DB\Connection->query(string)
   /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/config/option.php:182
#3: Bitrix\Main\Config\Option::load(string, NULL)
   /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/config/option.php:53
#4: Bitrix\Main\Config\Option::get(string, string, string)
   /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/httprequest.php:337
#5: Bitrix\Main\HttpRequest->prepareCookie(array)
   /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/httprequest.php:63
#6: Bitrix\Main\HttpRequest->__construct(object, array, array, array, array)
   /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/httpapplication.php:42
#7: Bitrix\Main\HttpApplication->initializeContext(array)
   /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/application.php:122
#8: Bitrix\Main\Application->initializeExtendedKernel(array)
   /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/include.php:23
#9: require_once(string)
   /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php:14
#10: require_once(string)
   /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog.php:10
#11: require_once(string)
   /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/header.php:1
#12: require(string)
   /home/bitrix/www/index.php:2
```

Подключение к БД правильное, во всяком случае в консоле по этому логин-паролю подключаюсь. Что делать то?

Comment: localhost не всегда 127.0.0.1  вернее будет сказать что если , например, в mysql настройках интерфейс биндится на 127.0.0.1 то подключаясь к БД как к  localhost может не работать.

Comment: А у Вас битрикс использует mysql или mysqli? Если первый, то все логично т.к. в php7 библиотека mysql не поддерживается и надо использовать mysqli. Битрикс умеет с ним работать надо только прописать использование mysqli в файлах настройки.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте не используют ли конфигурационные файлы битрикса `/bitrix/php_interface/dbconn.php` и `/bitrix/.settings.php` библиотеку `mysql`. Она не поддерживается уже давно, но в php7 уже нет механизма совместимости с ней.

Вам нужно перевести работу на библиотеку `mysqli` для этого в файле `/bitrix/php_interface/dbconn.php` вам нужно прописать строку:

```
define("BX_USE_MYSQLI", true);
```

И на всяки случай проверьте значение переменной `$DBHost` для работы на виртуалке от битрикса лучше всего чтобы было так:

```
$DBHost = "localhost";
```

А в файле `/bitrix/.settings.php` найти массив `connections` и в параметре `className` прописать вместо `\\Bitrix\\Main\\DB\\MysqlConnection` класс `\\Bitrix\\Main\\DB\\MysqliConnection`. Должно получиться так:

```
'connections' => 
  array (
    'value' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'className' => '\\Bitrix\\Main\\DB\\MysqliConnection',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'db_name',
        'login' => 'db_login',
        'password' => 'db_password',
        'options' => 2,
      ),
    ),
    'readonly' => true,
  ),
```